# How to get empty last elements from strsplit() in R?

Tags: r, string, csv, strsplit

I need to process some data that are mostly csv. The problem is that R ignores the comma if it comes at the end of a line (e.g., the one that comes after 3 in the example below).

```
> strsplit("1,2,3,", ",")
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

I'd like it to be read in as `[1] "1" "2" "3" NA` instead. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a couple ideas

```
scan(text="1,2,3,", sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
#[1]  1  2  3 NA

unlist(read.csv(text="1,2,3,", header=FALSE), use.names=FALSE)
#[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

---

Those both return integer vectors.  You can wrap `as.character` around either of them to get the exact output you show in the Question:

```
as.character(scan(text="1,2,3,", sep=",", quiet=TRUE))
#[1] "1" "2" "3" NA
```

Or, you could specify `what="character"` in `scan`, or `colClasses="character"` in `read.csv` for slightly different output

```
scan(text="1,2,3,", sep=",", quiet=TRUE, what="character")
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "" 

unlist(read.csv(text="1,2,3,", header=FALSE, colClasses="character"), use.names=FALSE)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" ""
```

You could also specify `na.strings=""` along with `colClasses="character"`

```
unlist(read.csv(text="1,2,3,", header=FALSE, colClasses="character", na.strings=""), 
       use.names=FALSE)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" NA
```

Answer (score 7):

Hadley's `stringi` (and previously `stringr`) libraries are a huge improvement on base string functions (fully vectorized, consistent function interface):

```
require(stringr)
str_split("1,2,3,", ",")

[1] "1" "2" "3" "" 

as.integer(unlist(str_split("1,2,3,", ",")))
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

Comment: `stringr` is slow, you should use `stringi` :)

Comment: @silvaran you are totally correct, I only became aware of `stringi` after I wrote this. (How on earth to stay on top of which-latest-greatest-package in R?)

Answer (score 3):

Using `stringi` package:

```
require(stringi)
> stri_split_fixed("1,2,3,",",")
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" "" 
## you can directly specify if you want to omit this empty elements
> stri_split_fixed("1,2,3,",",",omit_empty = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```